# Should I use many services to call a rest api in an angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-services

I'm developing my first angularjs application consuming a rest api.  I understand that I could use a service to call the rest api.

Let's say I have an api called acme.  In acme I could return a list of users and a list of activities.

Should I create one service file, let's say acmeService.js, that returns both the list of users and the list of activities along with any crud activity?

For example:

```
  this.getUsers = function(url){
    if (!url) {
      url = BASE_URL + '/users';
    }

    return $http.get(url);
  };
  // Code for User CRUD

  this.getActivities = function(url){
    if (!url) {
      url = BASE_URL + '/activities';
    }

    return $http.get(url);
  };
  // Code for Activity CRUD
```

Or should I create a service file for each entity along with its Crud operations?

For example:

userAcmeService.js

```
this.getUsers = function(url){
      if (!url) {
        url = BASE_URL + '/users';
      }

      return $http.get(url);
};
// Code for CRUD
```

activityAcmeService.js

```
this.getActivities = function(url){
      if (!url) {
         url = BASE_URL + '/activities';
      }

      return $http.get(url);
 };
 // Code for CRUD
```

I may be looking at this wrong but any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do either way honestly, I think that's completely up to you! You could just have one big service object with the 2 separated inside.

Also if you have CRUD operations within your REST API, why not try using `$resource`? It'll create all the methods for you!  `get / save / query / remove / delete`

**[$resource](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-restful-apis.html)**

As in the example:

```
app.factory("Post", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/posts/:id");
});

app.controller("PostIndexCtrl", function($scope, Post) {

    // This would "get all"
    Post.query(function( data ) {
        $scope.posts = data;
    });

});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

> **Note:** You have to include the angular-resource.js file before injecting it into a factory/service/etc

Comment: Thanks, feel a little better now about what to do next. I'll look into $resource.